# Magento 2 Override admin sales order history template

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override admin sales order history template. This is the code i have added in my xml file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name='order_tab_info'>
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>HK_Test::order/view/tab/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>

            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" name="order_info" template="HK_Test::order/view/info.phtml">
                <container name="extra_customer_info"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History" name="order_history" template="HK_Test::order/view/history.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Using this code i am able to override template. But issue is when i add new comment it loads default template. Check in attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override this file as well..

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_addcomment.xml

You can add above file here in your custom module.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_addcomment.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <referenceBlock name="order_history">
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>HK_Test::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </container>
</layout>
```

After adding above file just run below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean layout
php bin/magento cache:flush layout
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: You're welcome Buddy :)

Comment: Not working for me as well

Comment: @RamPratapSinghGour, what is the error?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya no error is coming, But My file not reflecting, Location of xml file:app/code/OM/CustomComments/view/adminhtml/Magento_Sales/layout and history.phtml : app/code/OM/CustomComments/view/adminhtml/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view

Comment: Can you show me your XML file?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya it's not working for me as well

Comment: @MageDev Please share your XML file content

Comment: <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <referenceBlock name="order_history">
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>CustomModule_Order::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </container>
</layout>

Comment: @KishanSavaliya file path should be :

app/code/CustomModule/Order/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_addcomment.xml

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your above code to override "Sales Order History template" but it's not working. can you please check again. I've confusion in "**Magento_Sales**" folder. Such as you mentioned app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_addcomment.xml

I've tried and placed file in "app/code/Custom/Modules/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_addcomment.xml"
but still not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_history">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Modules::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

`

I've used above code it is working fine on my local environment but not working production server.

Can you please help me what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

For me sales_order_addcomment.xml did not work. I used sales_order_view.xml instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name='order_history'>
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Vendor_CustomOrderView::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Note the use of the < body > tag, the < action > tag and my history.phtml file was located in Vendor/CustomOrderView/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view directory.